# TYPO3 Extbase FAL - How to update file metadata (sys_file) from frontend controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, fal

I have a frontend extensions where logged in users shall add/edit sys_file records.

I try to update the file metadata like this (simplified):

```
$uid = (int)$this->request->getArgument('file');
$resourceFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance();
$file = $resourceFactory->getFileObject($uid);

$file->updateProperties(array(
    'title'             => $this->request->getArgument('title'),
    'keywords'          => $this->request->getArgument('keywords'),
    'description'       => $this->request->getArgument('description'),
    'copyright'         => $this->request->getArgument('copyright'),
    'modification_date' => time()
));

$this->fileRepository->update($file);
$this->addFlashMessage(LocalizationUtility::translate('messages.success.file'));
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

persistenceManager and fileRepository are injected via:

```
/**
 * fileRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $fileRepository = NULL;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 * @inject
 */
protected $persistenceManager;
```

and generally I get no error, the flash message displays, the fluid form even shows the new data inside the form, but it is actually not saved.

Any way to debug/solve this? It seems the $fileRepository doesn't actually perform the "update" statement, is there some kind of permission check that I need to circumvent in the frontend?

Answer (score 6):

Kind of an old thread but there is a solution wich works in 7.6 and 8.x, as the Repository in 7.6 uses the `$GLOBAL['TYPO3_DB']` and in 8.x it's already migrated to Doctrine, so there is no need to rewrite your code.
Maybe it saves someone some time.

Use the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Index\MetaDataRepository` repository and just load it via objectManager.

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$metadata = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Index\MetaDataRepository');
```

then you can populate the metadata like this

```
$metadata->update($fileUid, $metadataInput);
```

The update method requires two params, the file uid and an array with db field names and values

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know  you have to update them by yourself with an update query:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->->exec_UPDATEquery('sys_file_metadata', 'file = ' . $fileUid, array('modification_date' => time()));
```

Comment: Hey René, thanks for your input. I actually did it like that and was hoping to only use that as a temporary hack. I did saw mention of a FileIndexRepository but it doesn't seem that this one can take a File Resource object to update its metadata?